# NOT Checking Replies after Pipelining w/HIREDIS

Tags: hiredis

Is there any harm in simply not calling redisGetReply() after calling redisAppendCommand() one or more times?   If I don't need the reply or need to check error conditions I was hoping to avoid the performance penalty. Or do I need to check and free every single reply generated from a pipelined command for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

There's not really any harm in that other than the fact that you won't be able to use the same `redisContext` if you want to send and read additional replies.

You can also tell Redis to not reply to your commands at all with the [CLIENT REPLY](https://redis.io/commands/client-reply/) command.